# how to calculate the diameter of an ellipse?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, ellipse

I have a work to calculate the diameter vertical and horizontal of an ellipse to determine the value of the cup to disk ratio of glaucoma. from the journal was im read, they are using fit ellipse methode. How might I do that?

[image]

Comment: There is no definition for the h/v diameter of an ellipse, and this is not an ellipse. Can you explain your need ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I just wanted to calculate the diameter of the sample images , to determine the value of the cup to disc ratio on in glaucoma.

Comment: @indraginanjarA.T This isn't a code writing service, try to implement it yourself and if you hit a **specific** problem come back and ask a question

Comment: @indraginanjarA.T: we cannot help you compute something that is undefined.

Comment: @YvesDaoust please, i just want to calculate the diameter from thats picture for my minithesis

Comment: I vote to close as you don't provide sufficient information.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to fit an ellipse using the Hough Transform.

But you can also find what you want using:

1. PCA => it will give you the main and secondary axises.
2. Moments

Comment: I'd definetly PCA this. Fast and accurate! good one.